# Keeps popping up W/: Zip: Invalid filename in android studio

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, zip

I'm trying to connect online SQL server on apps in android studio.
When I changed `Class.forName("java.sql.Driver")` into `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` and ran , my console kept popping message like this

```
    Zip: Invalid filename 
W/: Zip: Invalid filename 
W/: Zip: Invalid filename 
W/: Zip: Invalid filename 
    Zip: Invalid filename 
    Zip: Invalid filename 
    Zip: Invalid filename 
    Zip: Invalid filename 
    Zip: Invalid filename
```

Even though it could still connect to SQL server , I'm afraid that there might be some potential problems.
Here is part of my code

```
 try{
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/" + dbname;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename;
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    }
```

How could I deal with it , or what would cause this problem?

Comment: I solve it! By changing API level from 15 to 29 , it didn't show up again!

Comment: @timilao where you changed API level?

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj sorry for the time gap. I remember it is at build.gandle.

Comment: i'm stucked on this too, my build.gradle is setted to min 21

Comment: @AcauãPitta try 29

Comment: @timliao minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        compileSdkVersion 29

Comment: @AcauãPitta I'm not pretty sure.Mine minSdkVersion is set to 29.All the other are 29 as well.

Comment: @timliao for me it seem a jdbc versions issue, i'm using 5.1.47